# Interface between Database and File persistence

Tags: java, oop, serialization, persistence, dao

Recently I've started to build a tool for a browser game. It scrapes some data and shows it from a couple of useful perspectives.

Later on, after I've started development, I decided to turn it into a project of a course I'm taking in college; problem is that my professor did not want me to use a database to keep my data, but files instead, with serialized objects.

That would make my life harder and possibly kill some of the potential I had in mind for the tool. So he proposed that, if I really wanted to have a database, I would at least make it possible to choose files as a data persistence option. And the implementation he proposed was:

To build an interface from which I would implement classes with methods that saves data to a database, and classes with methods that serializes objects; then, choosing the persistence type would be just a matter of choosing the interface implementation. Like a DAO pattern.

I guess it would look something like this

```
/* I would choose the implementation here */
//DAO o = new SerializableDAOCarImpl(); // implementation for serializing data
DAO o = new DatabaseDAOCarImpl(); // implementation for interacting with a database

Car c = new Car();
o.add(c);
```

So far I've failed to do that. Is there something wrong with this plan? (I feel like there is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher give you a right hint, when you need a few ways to storage data of your application simple made this logic separately from another logic of application and hide it behind interface. Your program doesn't need to know how and where you store data, it only want to pass data to storage and retrieve. Even more if you have problems with serialization or something with storage part of application you may push it apart and concentrate on another logic after define contract with help of application saves and reads data. In example when you build a new PC you may assembly it in random order or even have only half of all parts in same time because all parts (hdd, memory, gpu, etc...) have own interfaces and all implementations from any company obeys to it's common interface.

Code of your application will be something like this

```
class GameClass {
    private final Dao dao;

    GameClass(Dao dao) { this.dao = dao; }

    void gameMethod() {
         Car car = new Car();
         dao.save(car);
    }

}
```

As you can see `GameClass` don't know what kind of implementation of Dao here, it only relies on contract.